# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Remote Desktop Connection Has Been Lost

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Recently purchased Windows Server 2012 R2, Remote desktop connection worked fine until we started getting disconnected every 2 or 3 seconds.

Message: Connecting, The connection has been lost. Attempting to reconnect to your session, Connection attempt: 1 of 20

We already tried fixing the problem by deleting recent updates, checking certificate validity, double checking networking problems, but no luck.

Please help! Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the Group Policies 

Navigate to  Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\ Remote Desktop Session Host\ Session Time Limits

 

1) Enable "Set time limit for disconnected session" to NEVER

 

2) Enable "Sets a time limit for active but idle Terminal Services sessions" to NEVER

Comment: While you're trying to connect, run a continuous ping to the server with the command `ping -t SERVER_IP`. Observe whether you have packet loss.